# Can I call a method using method chaining in a foreach loop that is inside another method in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, foreach, chaining

I have the following:

```
public static void ForEachIterationIn(IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in list)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

and am able to call it this way:

```
ForEachIterationIn(list, item => DoSomething(item));
```

Is it possible to use method chaining to do the following?

```
ForEachIterationIn(list).Do(item => DoSomething(item));
```

So that if I decide to, I can extend it and create something like:

```
ForEachIterationIn(list).RemoveWhen(item => item != 10);
```

Which means each method would basically do the following:

```
foreach(T item in list)
{
    Do(action(item));
    // Or RemoveWhen(action(item))
    // Or whatever method I use in the chain
}
```

Comment: Just use LINQ, that's it's whole premise, as a query building tool.

Comment: RemoveWhen should work on the list so ForEachIterationIn must return it. The purpose of ForEachIterationIn is then more or less gone i suppose. The logic to iterate and calling the delegate for each item is inside RemoveWhen.

Comment: If you can it to a `List`, you can use the `ForEach` method.  Or you could make your own.  But I'd stick with just LINQ here.

Comment: I'd advise you not to go down this route. Actually, scratch that. Let [Eric Lippert advise you not to go down that route](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) instead.

Comment: I am using the "params" argument to the enumerables I'm sending to it, which I believe makes it not possible for it to be a list unless I transformed it into a list.

It is possible that LINQ allows me to use it for this specific example but I wanted to learn how to do it and as I'm using Unity it might be that I need to do it for something that LINQ might not be able to (I'm not entirely sure what LINQ allows you to do), plus I wouldn't be needing to import the LINQ library for this.

Comment: In your example, what would "RemoveWhen()" do? You can't remove items from a sequence, but you can filter the sequence to produce a new sequence that  doesn't include those items. Or are you just wanting to use something like `List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)` (which of course only works with a `List<T>`)?

Comment: That was my bad, it was a bad example. I just meant that if I ever want to add a different type of action, I could do so by creating a method that would imply what that action was, and use it via method chaining, instead of sending the action via parameter.

So ForEachIterationIn(list).Sum(10) would for example add 10 to each list integer.

Right now I'm only using it to add styles to an element, so it would become:

ForEachIterationIn(list).AddStyleSheet(styleSheet) instead of ForEachIterationIn(list, item => item.addStyleSheet(styleSheet) every time I use it.

Comment: @IndieWafflus Again, all that is the kind of stuff LINQ is specifically designed to do.  Rather than re-creating an inferior imitation of LINQ, just use LINQ.  If there is an operation you can't do using it, then create your own method emulating it's style, namely a method accepting an IEnumerable and yielding a new IEnumerable with the relevant transformation applied.  If you don't know what LINQ can do then *take the time to learn what it can do* as that will be much easier and more effective than trying to re-create it from scratch yourself.

Comment: Personally I think that just doing `foreach (var e in list) e.addStyleSheet(styleSheet);` would be perfectly fine... It's only one character longer (including the two spaces).

Comment: In answer to your question, yes it is possible. The `ForEachIterationIn` method would need to return an object that has a `Do` or `RemoveWhen` method. You could write them all as extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`, and then just return the modified list from each of your extension methods. But unless you're just doing this for learning/fun, Linq supports just about anything you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below:

```
public class Iterator
    {
        public List<string> Items { get; set; }

        public Iterator(List<string> items)
        {
            Items = items;
        }

        public Iterator AddString(string s)
        {
            this.Items.Add(s);

            return this;
        }

        public Iterator AddAnotherString(string s)
        {
            this.Items.Add(s);

            return this;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Join('-', this.Items.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

And then use it:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
            var iterator = new Iterator(items);

            Console.WriteLine(iterator.AddString("c").AddAnotherString("d").ToString());

        }
    }
```